# How to express $y$ from $x^2+y^2>r$?

Tags: inequality, circles, graphing-functions, radicals

Consider an inequality in form of circle equation (with zero coordinates):

$$y^2 + x^2 > 1$$

Expressing $y$ step-by-step (maybe I wrong somewhere?):

$$y^2 > 1 - x^2  (1)$$

$$y>\sqrt{(1-x^2)}\space ∨ \space y<-\sqrt{(1-x^2)} (2)$$

For $-1 ≤x ≤1$ it sure will be like this:

[image]

But what about other $x$? If $Y$ belongs to $R$, there should not be any $y$ for $|x|>1$.

But, Wolfram Alpha, for some reason plots for all $x$:

[image]

Is it wrong, and it should be only from $-1$ to $1$?

Maybe I expressed $y$ wrong?

Comment: $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ makes only sense for $-1\leq x\leq 1$, but $x^2 +y^2>1$ makes sense for all $x$. So  e.g. for $x=-3$ we do have $(-3)^2+y^2>1$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$,

Comment: @PeterMelech, yeah, this is the problem, that I do not understand. Is not $y>\sqrt{(1-x^2)}\space ∧ \space y<-\sqrt{(1-x^2)}$ equal to $y^2 + x^2 > 1$?

Comment: No, it isn´t. That is actually what I wanted to point out. The second inequality makes sense for all $x$ the first doesn´t.

Comment: @PeterMelech, so is it some famous issue, I can read about somewhere, how to deal with, or it just "math fails, and that's it"?

Comment: The equality would be established like this $y^2+x^2>1\iff (x\in [-1,1] \land (y>\sqrt{(1-x^2)}\space ∧ \space y<-\sqrt{(1-x^2)})\lor x\notin [-1,1])$

Comment: @PeterMelech: Shouldn't it be $\left(x \in [-1,1] \wedge \left(\left(y>\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\vee\left(y<-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right)\right)$ in the first part? I usually suck in logic, so it is a good moment to learn something.

Comment: @Bernkastel Thank You, of course! Copy and paste error, lol. The equality would be established like this $y^2+x^2>1\iff (x\in [-1,1] \land (y>\sqrt{(1-x^2)}\space \lor \space y<-\sqrt{(1-x^2)})\lor x\notin [-1,1])$. Anyway You provide a better explanation in Your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the logical connective is $\vee$ and not $\wedge$; notice that there exists no real number $y$ such that $y>\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $y<-\sqrt{1-x^2}$, so that inequality describes the empty set.

About your question, the inequalities:
$$y^2>1-x^2$$
and
$$\left(y>\sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \vee \left(y<-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$$
are not equivalent. This is because the square root function is defined only for nonnegative values, hence in the very moment you introduce the square root you're imposing $-1 \le x \le 1$. But your first inequality $y^2>1-x^2$ has no constraint on $x$, hence they are not equivalent. A way to solve this problem is to split the sets where $x$ belongs to, and then take the union. You notice that when $x> 1$ or $x<-1$, we have $1-x^2<0$ and so the inequality $y^2>1-x^2$ is true for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$ because the left hand side is nonnegative and the right hand side is negative.

When $-1 \le x \le 1$, we have $1-x^2 \ge 0$ and so we can take the square root both sides of $y^2>1-x^2$, obtaining the result you've already obtained. Putting those results together, you have the exterior of the open circle of radius $1$ and center in the origin.

Comment: So, the trick is, that there is no algebraic operation $\sqrt(x)=y, y\in R$, but only $\sqrt(x)=y, y\in R and x≥0$. It will work for constant, yes, for example, we can say that there is no such operation $\sqrt(-1)$, but how do You state, that $1-x^2$, does not satisfy $x≥0$?

Comment: [Logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) (AND) is signed with upper symbol

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd: I haven't stated that $1-x^2$ does not satisfy $x \ge 0$, which is meaningless, I stated that $\sqrt{t}$ is defined in the reals only for $t \ge 0$. Hence, $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is real only for $1-x^2 \ge 0$ and so for $-1 \le x \le 1$. About the other comment, the correct logical connective is the logical disjunction "or", not the logical conjunction "and". The inequality $y^2>1-x^2$ is satisfied when $y>\sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $y<-\sqrt{1-x^2}$, this is written as $(y>\sqrt{1-x^2}) \vee (y<-\sqrt{1-x^2})$.

Comment: 1) So, why do You state then, that they are not equivalent, I did not understand? 2) Oh, yes, for bigger than sign, in case of AND (intersection), there will not be solutions, so there should be OR (union). And, if we wanted not an area outside the circle, but inside, we will need less than sign and AND vice-versa, since OR will give $y=(-∞,∞)$, and only AND will give $y=[-r,r]$?

Comment: (1): I already said the reason why they are not equivalent: $y^2>1-x^2$ is defined for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for each $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and depending on $x$ and $y$ it can be true or false. For instance, for $y=0$ and $x=-5$ is false. However, $y>\sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $y<-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ are both defined only for $-1 \le x \le 1$ because we've introduced the square root. So, there are values for which the do not make sense in the real numbers: for instance, $y=0$ and $x=-5$ gives $0>\sqrt{-24}$. This shows that they are not the same; if they were, they would be defined for the same values.

Comment: (2): You got the correct idea.